# Struct array initialization

Tags: arrays, data-structures, struct, initialization

```
     struct forces{
        double fo[1];
        double ft[1];
    };
    int main(void){
        struct forces frc;
        frc.fo[0]=6;
        frc.fo[1]=56;
        frc.ft[0]=567;
       printf("%.0lf\n",frc.fo[1]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Please assist. Why is my printout always  frc.ft[0]?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Is this C or C++?  You should tell us the language.  That aside, in both languages arrays are 0-based and only include N elements.  so int foo[5] has exactly 5 elements, foo[0] ... f[4].  foo[5] does not exist, and neither does frc.fo[1].

Answer (score 1):

With your declaration, fo[1] does not exist and writing to it is undefined behavior for C and C++.

Change your declaration to this to make fo[1] a valid element

```
struct forces{
    double fo[2];
    double ft[1];
};
```

In C and C++ (and most similar languages) a declaration of foo[5] creates a 5-element array with valid index values of [0] ... [4].  int foo[1] only has a valid index foo[0]

With your code you see fo[1] in place of ft[0] because your compiler placed the two double variables together in memory with no gap (padding) between them.

Comment: Thank you. This c code. This is a common mistake I overlooked. I will give it a go.